# Is there a easy way to get the data with timestamp == yesterday?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a easy way to get the data with timestamp == yesterday?

I just want the data of yesterday.

```
SELECT
 COUNT(t0.user_id) AS t0_qt_AC5uO9oi
FROM
 `{something here}` AS t0
WHERE
 (t0.event_type = 'XXXXX')
ORDER BY
 t0_qt_AC5uO9oi ASC;
```

Not sure what is the best way.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  CURRENT_DATE() today, 
  DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) yesterday
```

Assuming that you are asking for how to get yesterday's date!
Then of course you need to use it in your query respectively

for example

```sql
WHERE t0.event_date = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
```

Comment: Use `CAST(string_timestamp_column AS TIMESTAMP)` to get it as a `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: Thanks. I just modified the field to "timestamp" instead of "string". But now, I just the original answer above, I am seeing this error: Error: No matching signature for operator = for argument types: TIMESTAMP, DATE. Supported signature: ANY = ANY at [8:9]

   SELECT
       COUNT(DISTINCT t0.user_id) AS unique_device
    FROM
      `TableName` AS t0
    WHERE
       (t0.event_type = 'XXXX'
       AND t0.game_id = 'XXXX'
       AND t0.timestamp = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 
      DAY))

Comment: `AND DATE(t0.timestamp) = DATE_ADD(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Add-in to [the answer of Mikhail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47318110/5668956),
if `(today) + (-1) day` is not so natural to read, then let [DATE_SUB](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date_sub) solves it

```sql
SELECT DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS yesterday;

+---------------+
| yesterday     |
+---------------+
| 2022-06-29    |
+---------------+
```