# How to have a calculate field 'Yesterday' in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I tried to add calculate field in Google Data Studio based on timestamp.
case when timestamp = yesterday then 1 else 0 end as yesterday.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a easy way to get the data with timestamp == yesterday?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47318015/is-there-a-easy-way-to-get-the-data-with-timestamp-yesterday)

Comment: Not in Data Studio, although @zkohi's link is BigQuery specific, he's right in as much as you'd need to set it up in your data source.

Answer (score 0):

There's a function, [`DATETIME_SUB`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9699809) that subtracts the number of days. For example, with a calculated field on a date to get today, like `TODAY('date')` , you could get yesterday like that:

```
DATETIME_SUB(TODAY('date'), INTERVAL 1 DAY
```